# Unable to import tensorflow_addons

Tags: tensorflow

I did a pip install for the tensorflow_addons module. Then when I execute import tensorflow_addons, I'm getting the error below. How to fix this?
tf.**version** prints this'1.13.1'. but when I checked the versions through anaconda prompt conda list -n base I found these

> tensorboard               2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
> tensorflow                2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
> tensorflow-addons         0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
> tensorflow-datasets       3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
> tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
> tensorflow-gpu            1.13.1               h0d30ee6_0    anaconda
> tensorflow-metadata       0.21.2                   pypi_0    pypi

I tried this on both Windows and Ubuntu systems. same error on both systems.
[pip install output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEsqZ.png)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBpoV.png)

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem today on google colaboratory, but both solution did not work for me, maybe it's a problem with the current versions in 2022.

To solve the problem i had to tweak the two versions of tf and tf addons.
So if in the future you have the same problem try to change the number of the 2 versions.

In the end i manage to solve without reinstalling tf like this:

```
!pip install tensorflow-addons==0.16.1
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

This is enough right now.

Answer (score 5):

Google Colab

```
!pip install tensorflow-addons==0.8.3
!pip install tensorflow==2.2.0-rc3
```

And after that

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer for this problem. There is some bug in the above versions of tensorflow and tensorflow-addons  modules. All you have to do is pip install the below mentioned versions and it will work.

```
pip install --user tensorflow-addons==0.8.3
pip install --user tensorflow==2.2.0-rc3
```

now you can import tensorflow_addons.  I simply checked the versions installed in google colab link given in the official tensor flow addons page and changed my versions to that.

[The screen shot of google colab code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x7DP.png)

Answer (score 2):

Before installing tensorflow-addons, please check the compatible version of tensorflow-addons with your TF & Python version.

You can refer this for compatibility match:

[image]

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons

For checking TF version

```
tf.__version__
```

For checking Python version

```
!python --version
```

Let say you got TF version: 2.9.2 & Python version: 3.8.16. From the compatibility sheet, the latest version you can install is 'tensorflow-addons-0.19.0'

To install tensorflow-addons:

```
!pip install tensorflow-addons==0.19.0
```

Now, we can import tensorflow addons like this

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

Answer (score 0):

On your conda environment

`pip install tensorflow-addons`

Answer (score 0):

In in Jupyter Notebook (this works well for me):

```
%conda install -q -U tensorflow_addons
```

or

```
%pip install -q -U tensorflow_addons
```

OR

In your terminal:

```
pip install -q -U tensorflow_addons
```

https://blog.finxter.com/fixed-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-addons/

For more information, please visit the official website here: [tensorflow optimizers cyclical learningrate](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/optimizers_cyclicallearningrate)

Comment: Use of the exclamation point in conjunction with install commands is outdated and you should be suggesting the magic variations `%pip install` and `%conda install` instead. This is current best practice as those commands were added in 2019 to overcome the issues that can arise doing what you suggest because with the exclamation along there is no guarantee it will install to the environment where the kernel is running. See more about the modern magic install commands [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).